# How to make discord bot automatically send direct message [Discord.py]

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I can send direct message through discord bot if I type something to trigger the event. But I don't know the way to let discord bot automatically send direct message when It meet specific condition

Answer (score 0):

You would first setup your bot and have it run. An example of this would be

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "this triggers" in message.content:
        await message.author.send("I just dmed you this message")
```

To check if it is in a guild `message.guild != None` will return `True` and `message.guild.id == 1232131231231` will check if the guild's/server's id is `1232131231231`

Comment: I think you need to `await` the author.send

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for your query:

To make it send on command, do:

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send("Hello, this is a DM!")
```

and then to make it send on an on_message trigger do:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "dm" == message.content.lower()
        await message.author.send("Hello, this is a DM!")
```

What happens is to send a dm, send a message to the author. It's as simple as that. But for the on_message, we check if the message is "dm" in which case it dm's you.